# If else statement with a value that is part of a continuous character in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

My dataframe (df) contains a list of values which are labelled following a format of 'Month' 'Name of Site' and 'Camera No.'. I.e., if my value is 'DECBUTCAM27' then Dec-December, BUT-Name of Site and CAM27-Camera No.

I have 100 such values with 19 different site names.

I want to write an If else code such that only the site names are recognised and a corresponding number is added.

My initial idea was to add the corresponding number for all the 100 values, but since if else does not work beyond 50 values I couldnt use that option.

This is what I had written for the option that i had tried:

```
    df <- df2 %>% mutate(Site_ID =
ifelse (CT_Name == 'DECBUTCAM27', "1",
ifelse (CT_Name == 'DECBUTCAM28', "1",
ifelse (CT_Name == 'DECI2NCAM01', "2",
ifelse (CT_Name == 'DECI2NCAM07', "2",
ifelse (CT_Name == 'DECI5CAM39', "3",
ifelse (CT_Name == 'DECI5CAM40', "3","NoVal")))))))
```

I am looking for a code such that only the sites i.e., 'BUT', 'I2N' and 'I5' would be recognised and a corresponding number is added.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the sitename using regex and use `match` + `unique` to assign unique number.

```
df2$site_name <- sub('...(.*)CAM.*', '\\1', df2$CT_Name)
df2$Site_ID <- match(df2$site_name, unique(df2$site_name))
```

---

For example, see this example :

```
CT_Name <- c('DECBUTCAM27', 'DECBUTCAM28', 'DECI2NCAM07', 'DECI2NCAM01', 
             'DECI5CAM39', 'DECI5CAM40')
site_name <- sub('...(.*)CAM.*', '\\1', CT_Name)
site_name
#[1] "BUT" "BUT" "I2N" "I2N" "I5"  "I5" 
Site_ID <- match(site_name, unique(site_name))
Site_ID
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

Comment: Can you explain what your sub does wit `'\\1'` ? I never saw this before and it look interesting ^^

Comment: It is used as back reference to capture the pattern in capture group which here is `(.*)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example using regex to find the site code and using an apply function to return a vector of code.

```
df <- data.frame(code = c('DECBUTCAM27','JANBUTCAM27','DECDUCCAM45'))

df$loc <- apply(df, 1, function(x) gsub("CAM.*$","",gsub("^.{3}",'',x[1])))

unique(df$loc) # all the location of the file

df$n <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$loc)) # get a number for each location
```

Mind that here I use the `x[1]` because the code are in the first column of my data.frame, which may vary for you.

---EDIT--- This was a previous answer also working but with more work for you to do. However it allow you to choose numeric code value (or text) to assign locations if they are ordered for example.

It require you to put all the codes for each site, which I found heavy in term of code but it works. The switch part is roughly the same as an ifelse.

The regex consist in excluding the 3 first character and the other ones at the end after the 'CAM' sequence.

```
df <- data.frame(code = c('DECBUTCAM27','JANBUTCAM27','DECDUCCAM45'))

df$n <- apply(df, 1, function(x) switch(gsub("CAM.*$","",gsub("^.{3}",'',x[1])),
              BUT = 1,
              DUC = 2)
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

1. You haven't provided a reproducible example, but let's use the CT_Names that you have supplied to create a test dataframe:

```
data <- tribble(
    ~ CT_Name,
    "DECBUTCAM27",
    "DECBUTCAM28",
    "DECI2NCAM01",
    "DECI2NCAM07",
    "DECI5CAM39",
    "DECI5CAM40"
  )
```

2. Let's assume that the string format is 3 letters for months, 2 or more letters or numbers for site and CAM + 1 or more digits for camera number (adjust these as needed). We can use a regular expression in `tidyr`'s `extract()` function to split up the string into its components:

```
data_new <- data %>% 
   extract(CT_Name, regex = "(\\w{3})(\\w{2,})(CAM\\d+)", into = c("Month", "Site", "Camera"))
```

(add `remove = FALSE` if you want to keep the original CT_Name variable)

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Month Site  Camera
  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 DEC   BUT   CAM27 
2 DEC   BUT   CAM28 
3 DEC   I2N   CAM01 
4 DEC   I2N   CAM07 
5 DEC   I5    CAM39 
6 DEC   I5    CAM40
```

3. We can then group by site and assign a group ID as your Site_ID:

```
data_new <- data %>% 
   extract(CT_Name, regex = "(\\w{3})(\\w{2,})(CAM\\d+)", into = c("Month", "Site", "Camera")) %>%
   group_by(Site) %>%
   mutate(Site_ID = cur_group_id())
```

This produces:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Site [3]
  Month Site  Camera Site_ID
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <int>
1 DEC   BUT   CAM27        1
2 DEC   BUT   CAM28        1
3 DEC   I2N   CAM01        2
4 DEC   I2N   CAM07        2
5 DEC   I5    CAM39        3
6 DEC   I5    CAM40        3
```